# nginx: How to mass permanent redirect from a given list?

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have about 400 url that will change in the new version and for some reasons I can't repeat the same type of url structure in the new website.

My question is, can I give a url list to nginx (yeah I know the 400 ones), and tell him simply that each one of them are going to another url?

Like I said the url structure will be different so I can't use any type of pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55):

## The `map` directive

If you have a very long list of entries, it could be a good idea to keep them outside of the nginx configuration file - using a **.map** file.

First you need to add a `map` directive inside your `nginx.conf` file - keep in mind that your `.conf` file could be named in another way (e.g. `default.conf`).

**nginx.conf**

```
map_hash_bucket_size 256; # see http://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html

map $request_uri $new_uri {
    include /etc/nginx/oldnew.map; # or any file readable by nginx
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  your_server_name;

    if ($new_uri) {
       return 301 $new_uri;
    }

    ...    
}
```

Then, the `map` directive will map any `$request_uri` to the matching `$new_uri` found inside the `oldnew.map` file.

**/etc/nginx/oldnew.map**:

```
/my-old-url /my-new-url;
/old.html /new.html;
```

> Be sure to end each line with a ";" char!

---

### Additional configuration

If you need to redirect all URLs to another host, you can use:

```
return 301 http://example.org$new_uri;
```

Or, if you also need to redirect to another port, you can use:

```
return 301 http://example.org:8080$new_uri;
```

Comment: the maps should contain ';' at the end of each  line else it causes EOL error

Comment: Thank you @paimpozhil for the missing detail

Comment: Refer https://web.archive.org/web/20190911162035/https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-nginx-s-map-module-on-ubuntu-16-04 for explanations

Comment: I'm sorry @TummalaDhanvi but your edit was wrong: please double check the linked article because it's exaclty the same as in my answer.

Comment: I realized that after making the edit, there wasn't a feature to cancel the edit, so I was waiting for the edit to get approved or rejected. I should have updated here about my wrong edit. Apologies for my mistake. Thank You! for your answer :)

Comment: how can we add parameters too in this redirection ?

Comment: @jpk please ask another question with a complete example

Answer (score 13):

Probably the easiest way to do that is to wrap [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive around your list. The configuration in this case would look like this:

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
    default "";
    /old/page1.html /new/page1.html;
    /old/page2.html /new/page2.html;
    ...
}

server {
    ...

    if ($new_uri != "") {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $new_uri permanent;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is the `default` line necessary? The docs say "When default is not specified, the default resulting value will be an empty string.".