# nginx: [emerg] conflicting parameter (mass redirect using nginx / map)

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am in process of migrating an old site to a new platform. I have a huge list of urls to forward onto new urls. The way I have implemented this is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40576333/2332336) answer:

```
map_hash_bucket_size 256; # see http://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html

map $request_uri $new_uri {
    include /etc/nginx/oldnew.map; #or any file readable by nginx
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  your_server_name;

    if ($new_uri) {
       return 301 $new_uri;
    }

    ...    
}
```

**/etc/nginx/oldnew.map**

```
... other links ...
/Catalogue/Navigate/category-paints-thinners    /parts-by-category/paint-accessories.html;
/Catalogue/Navigate/category-paints-thinners?catalogueLevelItemID=87529237-3f1f-4e4e-aedd-ac48c4deb5cd  /parts-by-category/paint-accessories.html;
... other links ...
```

When I start the nginx server, I am getting this error:

> nginx[32448]: nginx: [emerg] conflicting parameter
>   "/catalogue/navigate/category-paints-thinners" in
>   /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirects.map:4993

Any idea what's causing this error? is it the query string? if so, how do you deal with it?

Comment: Are you sure that `/catalogue/navigate/category-paints-thinners` (ignoring case) does not appear earlier in the file?