# Better way of creating static pages with *.html extensions in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a website which is fully in built in HTML (all the links have *.htm extension). I am developing a dynamic version of this website using Django, but I don't want the old links of the old website to be broken, because there may many people refer to those links.

So what I am doing right now based on my knowledge is creating url patterns for each link like below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # static pages below
    url(r'^children.htm', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home/children.htm'), name='children'),
]
```

It works fine, but I wonder whether this way is valid or not AND I want to know whether there is any other better way of doing it?

Comment: I'd suggest to produce a .map file for nginx (webserver) to redirect all the old links to new views without `.html`

Comment: @IvanStarostin I am newbie. Can you please give more clarification about how to do that? It sounds good :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354142/nginx-how-to-mass-permanent-redirect-from-a-given-list

Comment: Do all the links have `htm` extension, or `html` extension? Because you're asking about `htm`, but have `html` in your `urlpatterns`.

Comment: @cezar all of the pages have .htm extension. I have updated the question, thanks. But does that make difference now?

Comment: Yes, it makes - for other users who will read the question in few months or in few years. The ambiguity is harming the readability and comprehension of the question. There is still a mismatch between the title, the text and the code example. As far as I understand, you have existing `htm` pages and you want to preserve external links to them. Therefore it is right to have `r'^children.htm`, but it doesn't mean that the template needs also `htm` extension. It can be `home/children.html`', or whatever you want, even something like this: `home/new_page_children.html`.

Comment: Thanks, @cezar !

Comment: How would you set a title for this question? ^^