# Varnish: How to efficiently Mass map permanent 302 redirects from a given list

Tags: nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl

We are in the process of migrating sites and need to setup a large amount of 302 redirects accordingly in Varnish. What is the best way to do this in mass? I am trying to avoid having a large amount of 'if else if' statements if possible...

Essentially what I am looking for is something similar to this, but in Varnish : [nginx: How to mass permanent redirect from a given list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354142/nginx-how-to-mass-permanent-redirect-from-a-given-list)

**(Varnish Version 4.1.9)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way would be to use [Vmod-dbrw](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/vmod-dbrw/). This Varnish VMOD implements database-driven rewrite rules.

For CentOS/RHEL 7, it is available as a RPM package from *commercial* GetPageSpeed repository [here](https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/vmod-dbrw.html).

For other distros, you will likely end up compiling it from the source.